# Why do some servers/applications send a second HTTP status header

Tags: php, apache, http

Why do some web applications/servers/etc issue a non-standard, second, `Status` header.  For example, I'm working with an existing application where, in addition to that `HTTP` protocal line, there's a second header named status

```
$ curl -I 'http://example.com/404'
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
//...
Status: 404 Not Found
//...
```

and a stock apache 404 doesn't include it

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 13:16:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I'd write this off as one quirky application developer, but I've seen this behavior is other applications over the years, and the Wikipedia article on [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) mentions this header, although it points out the header isn't included in RFC7230.

> ? "Status" is not listed as a registered header. The "Status-Line" of a "Response" is defined by RFC7230[23] without any explicit "Status:" header name.

Does anyone know the deal here?  Is there some browser that needed this at some point? Still needs it?  Is this some weird bit of SEO voodoo?

Is there any practical effect to including/not-including this field?  Has there ever been?

(I'm specifically working with PHP, if that matters)

Comment: Those are likely just remnants from PHP not [transforming](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.rfc2616-headers) `Status: xy` into the according HTTP head itself. I'd surmise it happens mostly for FastCGI setups and e.g. setuid wrapper scripts that it's left there by Apache.

Comment: @mario +1 for interesting context — but in this case the application framework is explicitly setting both the HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found and the `Status: 404 Not Found` header.